# FormsAuthentication Redirect cross site

Tags: asp.net, formsauthentication

I've 2 web site. From  web site 1 I need to execute login into website 2 and return to original requested url (requested url of website 1).

On login click, whan I execute  Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl("...", false)) I always achieve something like "http://website2/requestedPage.aspx", instead, I should getting the first website : "http://website1/requestedPage.aspx".

In other words, GetRedirectUrl method aòways assume that I'm working in the same domina, so web site name is implied.

Of course I could to explicit webSite name, but I don't want it because tomorrow, maybe I'll have to do login from another one web site.

Is there a simple way to get web site name that required login function?

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible because forms authentication is bind to one domain only, the forms authentication needs an cookie to verify and cookies can only be set for a specific domain.

If you want to setup a login for multiple sites you have to look at an single sign-on solution.

Comment: I'm using single sign on. I only need to redirect to exact page without implied I'm working on the same domain. Please read my example. What I need is only a simple way to get "returnUrl" including siteName.

Comment: single sign on solution seems not wroks. Evenry time I try ti execute some postback after atuhenticationI get redirect to login page. I've right setted config, machine key and so on. Exist Any reliabe tutorial?

Comment: What kind of single signon method do you use? and how did you set it up.

Comment: I did follow this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27576/Single-Sign-on-in-ASP-NET-and-Other-Platforms

Comment: I think the best you can do is submit a new question, with some code and configuration samples.

Comment: ok, I've posted another one question to better clarify my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12252783/authenticationform-cookie-cross-site