# AuthenticationForm - Cross Site Cookies

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, httpcookie

I've 2 web sites, the first one is `myFirst.domain.com` and the second one is `mySecondSite.domain.com`.

They stay on two different web servers and my goal is to allow cross site authentication (my real need is shared `FormsAuthentication` Cookie).

I've correctly set up my `web.config` file (machine key node, forms node). The only difference is about loginUrl where on myFirstSite appears like `~/login.aspx`, and on mySecondSite it appears like `http://myFirstSite.com/login.aspx`.

Note that I've not got a virtual directory, I've just 2 different web apps.

The problem: When I reach myFirstSite login page from mySecondSite I never get redirected from the login page, it seems like a cookie isn't being written.

The following is a few snippets about the issue:

MyFirsSite:

```
 <machineKey validationKey="..." decryptionKey="..." validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" name="authCookie" enableCrossAppRedirects="true"></forms>
        </authentication>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
```

MyFirstSite code behind:

```
 FormsAuthenticationTicket fat = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, "userName..", DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), true, "roles..");

        string ticket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(fat);

        HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, ticket);
        authCookie.Expires = fat.Expiration;
        authCookie.Domain = "myDomain.com";
        Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);

//Here is other stuff about querystring checking in order to execute exact redirect, however it's not working, I always return to the login page.
```

MySecondSite:

```
<machineKey validationKey="..." decryptionKey="..." validation="SHA1" decryption="AES"/>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="http://myFirstSite.domain.com/login.aspx?queryStringToIndicateUrlPage" enableCrossAppRedirects="true"></forms>
        </authentication>
        <authorization>
```

Well, that's all. Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Please, don't pay attention to `queryStringToIndicateUrlPage`, it's only a simple workaround in order to know whether I must redirect on the same app or on the another one.

Answer (score 0):

As you're using cookie based authentication shared between two domains, you'll need to indicate this in the `<forms>` element:

```
<machineKey validationKey="..." decryptionKey="..." validation="SHA1" decryption="AES"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms domain=".domain.com" ... />
    </authentication>
```

Note the initial "." in front of the domain name, which enables sharing of cookies between subdomains.

Comment: I've already tryied by specifying domain name but it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: @bit: Your sample code uses authCookie.Domain = "myDomain.com", it should be ".myDomain.com". Did you try that?

Comment: Yes I did. I did try many other solutions too without luck.. It seems impossibile to achieve.

Comment: Important: in my example I said myFirstSite.myDomain.com and mySecondSite.MyDomain.com for semplcity. In reality, the address are myFirstSite.xxx.yyy.com and mySecondSite.xxx.yyy.com, so my cookie domain string will be ".xxx.yyy.com". I've read that more than 2 dot can be cause of bad issue. Is it possibile?

Comment: @bit: The first thing I'd check if I were you is whether the cookies actually stick. Forget about the authentication after that, can you see the cookies being set properly? Look at the Set-Cookie and Cookie headers with a network tracer (IE has that built in, you can use Firebug under Firefox).